# Use of the bang?

Tags: ruby

Some people say that the bang `!` indicates the method "may" modify the object.

In this example:

```
foo = "A STRING"
foo.downcase
puts foo
# => A STRING
foo.downcase!
puts foo
# => a string
```

the bang symbol appears to be causing a side effect. Is `obj.method!` equivalent to `obj = obj.method`? If not, why? Is there some method for which these two expressions are not equivalent?

Comment: Are you asking whether the bang method is functionally equivalent to the reassignment? In most cases, probably yes, but it really depends on the method.

Comment: @ZachKemp Yes, that's exactly what I'm asking.

Comment: The bang is part of the function name. It is nothing other than part of the method name.

Comment: @Dave Then how does that explain the example?

Comment: @Tom ... The function with the bang in its name modifies the object. The function without the bang doesn't. What makes you think it's the exclamation point causing the side effect? Where's the cognitive hangup in accepting it's a name, and it's the function itself that matters?

Comment: In your example, `foo` and `foo.downcase!` has the same `object_id` while `foo.downcase` has a different one.

Comment: Pretty heavy-handed editing, @sawa.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The bang ! in a method name means "danger" in general.

- It is a method naming convention, *not* an operator, *not* a rule.
- It typically means warning, or mutation, or irreversable, or raises an exception, etc.

We often use "!" as a naming convention to distiguish two similar methods:

- The normal method name returns a result.
- The "!" method name does something dangerous.

Made up examples of "!" meaning mutation:

```
obj.change #=> return a new object that has the change.
obj.change! #=> do the change by mutating the object.
```

Made up examples of "!" meaning "raises an error":

```
obj.save #=> if the object can't save, then return false.
obj.save! #=> if the object can't save, then raise an exception.
```

Made up examples of "!" to mean "DANGER" or "cannot be undone":

```
obj.exit #=> exit normally, running all exit handlers.
obj.exit! #=> exit immediately, skipping all exit handlers.
```

All of these are just naming conventions, where the developer has chosen to provide two similarly-named methods.

Comment: Purely a naming convention? The bang does affect whether or not the object is modified. This is what I'm talking about: https://gist.github.com/twslankard/4982278

Comment: @Tom No, the bang itself does *not* affect whether or not the object is modified: it's a *naming convention*. For example, Rails' `save` vs. `save!`.

Comment: And some methods only have a bang version to indicate that they perform some sort of irreversible operation (e.g. ActiveRecord's `readonly!`).

Comment: I think I'm misunderstanding you, @joelparkerhenderson. Are you saying that the bang symbol does not affect whether or not the object is modified?

Comment: @Tom: Those are two separate methods, one named `downcase` and the other named `downcase!`. By convention, the version with a bang on the end of its name is the one that mutates the object rather than returning a new object. But it's not like the bang "affects" the method. It's not an operator in this case — it's part of the name.