# Calling multiple methods on a variable

Tags: ruby

So I have the following code:

```
print "input please: "
user_input = gets.chomp.downcase!

if user_input.include? "s"
  user_input.gsub!(/s/, "th")
else 
  puts "There is no S in your input"
end
```

which throws me an error regarding the include method

when I run this it works:

```
print "input please "
user_input = gets.chomp
user_input.downcase!

if user_input.include? "s"
  user_input.gsub!(/s/, "th")
else 
  puts "There is no S in your input"
end
```

is it not possible to call multiple methods on a variable?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: this is what I get : main.rb:4:in `<main>': undefined method `include?' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Comment: You might be interested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/14948228/2166798 for a more generic view of what's happening.

Comment: As an aside, your code could be replaced with the following. `obj = gets.chomp.downcase.gsub!(/s/, "th"); puts 'There is no S in your input' if obj.nil?; obj`. That's because `gsub!` returns `nil` if there is no match. (I'm not advocating this.)

Comment: Calling multiple methods on the same object is called [method cascading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_cascading) – a feature that Ruby unfortunately doesn't have. You can of course use method chaining, but you have to take each method's return value into account. For example, `gets` can already return `nil`. (try hitting ctrl-d when prompted for input)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is permissible (and recommended!) to chain methods in Ruby as you have done with `gets.chomp.downcase!`. However, using `downcase!` as opposed to the form `downcase` is causing an unexpected behavior in your code. [According to the docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/String.html#method-i-downcase!), the `downcase!` form

> Downcases the contents of str, **returning nil if no changes were made**.

So if your input does not contain any *upper* case letters, `downcase!` returns `nil` and that causes an error down the line when you call `.include?` on it. Try it out with input like this string:

```
input please: No letter in here!
# prints
There is no S in your input
```

But the same called without the upper `N` errors:

```
input please: no letter in here!
Traceback (most recent call last):
test.rb:4:in `<main>': undefined method `include?' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

If you supply input that does contain upper case characters, you'll get no error with your original code.  The fix for this is to use the non-`!` form:

```
# Don't use the ! form of downcase
user_input = gets.chomp.downcase
```

Because the `downcase!` form is intended to modify a *variable* rather than modify a transient string such as the string returned by `.chomp`.

I suspect you intended to `puts user_input` there also, following your `.gsub!` call. Your string replacement `s` to `th` does work correctly if you add that in.

Comment: thank you very much for your thorough explanation and solution !!!